# Increase count value of hardware timer (on µC) more than one at each timer tick

Tags: timer, microcontroller, hardware, cortex-m

Has anyone heard of a hardware-timer which can count by different values with one timer tick?

Normally a timer of a µC counts up or down by one. But I have a challenge where I need to add e.g. 500 each timer tick.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple options for your question. Depending on your microcontroller and timer you could:

- Use the interrupt generation of the timer to manually up a variable by a set amount. `500` in your case.
- Change the timer prescalers such that instead of 500 times in an expected period, the timer only triggers once during the expected period.

I personally don't know of a timer that has a variable increase amount but that doesn't mean that it doesn't exist. Maybe creating such a timer in VHDL or verilog may be a option.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
My application is a little bit "special" ;)
Using an Interrupt and counting in the Interrupt would not work, because I need my computing power for my main application.

Changing the prescaler wouldn't work because I need the full speed of the timer :(

A hardware with VHDL would also be my best solution, but it would be to expensiv for my application.

Comment: Sounds like you need to re-evaluate the problem and why you think this will fix it.  What is the problem that this is the solution.   These are your two available choices.

Comment: Why not just multiply the timer value by 500 when you need it?  If you can be flexible about the multiplier, a power of two (e.g. 512) would allow you, or the compiler, to use a shift rather than a multiply if you're that resource-constrained.

Comment: @cooperised if interrupt addition isn't allowed then shifting is probably also too slow

Comment: @TarickWelling: Why bit shifting should be too expensive? Depending on the hardware this should cost not more than a few assembler instructions. A multiplication with 500 might be expensive, a multiplication with 512 will be much cheaper and a factor of 256 will be a bargain.

Comment: @TarickWelling If the tag of 'cortex-m' is to be believed then it's a single cycle instruction at worst; and it could even be free, because the flexible second operand of many of the data processing instructions allows a bit shift at no additional cost.

Comment: Some Cypress MCUs have "universal digital blocks" with 32 bit registers. You could implement a 500-step timer there, without needing to implement or write actual VHDL.